# How to draw multi line text and rotate it on canvas in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-canvas, android-custom-view, android-drawable

I would like achieve below screen design on my custom view using canvas. Also I need to set Multi-Line Text based on X, Y coordinates.

[image]

What is the best way

1) Using Static Layout and Rotate
2) TextView + Linear Layout and Rotate.

With Static layout, I am able to write and rotate multi line text, but it is not getting placed based on X,Y values

below is my code

```
TextPaint tp = new TextPaint();
    tp.setColor(Color.RED);
    tp.setTextSize(50);
    tp.setAntiAlias(true);
    StaticLayout mTextLayout = new StaticLayout("My Sample multiline text", tp, canvas.getWidth() - 300, Alignment.ALIGN_NORMAL, 1.0f, 0.0f, false);
    canvas.save();

    canvas.translate(posX, posY);
    canvas.translate(-posX, -posY);
    canvas.rotate(90,posX, posY);
    mTextLayout.draw(canvas);
    canvas.restore();
```

Any suggestions or sample are most welcome. Thanks In Advance.

Answer (score 0):

Setting PivotX and PivotY to zero, solved the problem of Texview Position jumping after rotate 90F. Below is the code that worked for me.

```
private void addTextViewOnCanvas(Canvas canvas) {

    LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(_context);
    TextView textView = new TextView(_context); 
    textView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    textView.setText("Hello Multiline text world .............");
    textView.setWidth(canvas.getWidth() - 100);
    textView.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);
    textView.setPivotX(0);
    textView.setPivotY(0);
    textView.setRotation(90F);
    layout.addView(textView);
    layout.measure(canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());
    layout.layout(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());

    // To place the text view somewhere specific:
    canvas.translate(_PosX, _PosY);
    layout.draw(canvas);

}
```

Answer (score -2):

I would be quite confident you could achieve something like that using a simple rotated TextView, within a Relative / Linear Layout if you wanted to.

```
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/sidewaysText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:lines="2"
        android:rotation="90"
        android:text="My sample multiline text"
        android:textColor="#FF0000" />
```

Moreover, using the already written android rotate functions in the View, would almost certainly be more performant than something you or I could write ourselves.

Good Luck!

Comment: I would like have it dynamically on custom view not on static layouts.

Comment: Firstly, you say nothing of the sort in your question.

Secondly, you can easily create a new TextView dynamically in code, which you can then use.

No need for the downvote, that wont make you friends here.